# Sub or Function not defined. Trying to use macro to save Email Attachments in Outlook for Office 365 ProPlus Version 16.0

Tags: vba, outlook

Was following along here and trying to use this to save files.
https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/saveatt.htm

I get a compile error whenever I try to run the macro.

Searched all of the web and multiple people state that this code works for them but not for me.

I Made sure that the folder I reference under  was created. Also made sure the subfolder; "MyFolder" was created in my email Inbox.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
'Arg 1 = Folder name of folder inside your Inbox
'Arg 2 = File extension, "" is every file
'Arg 3 = Save folder, "C:\Users\Ron\test" or ""
'        If you use "" it will create a date/time stamped folder for you 
in your "Documents" folder
'        Note: If you use this "C:\Users\Ron\test" the folder must exist.

SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "", 
"C:\Users\my_name\Documents\ProjectX"

End Sub
```

I expected the attachments to show up. But it seems like the Function SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder does not work.

Comment: Did you add all the `SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder` code to your module? It's the last half or so of the linked webpage.

Comment: That was it BigBen. I didn't realize it was in 2 segments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The following should all be under 1 module*

```
public Sub Test()

    SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder "MyFolder", "", "C:\Users\my_name\Documents\ProjectX"

End Sub


Public Sub SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder(OutlookFolderInInbox As String, _
                                 ExtString As String, DestFolder As String)
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim MyDocPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim wsh As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    On Error GoTo ThisMacro_err

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(OutlookFolderInInbox)

    I = 0
    ' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in this folder : " & OutlookFolderInInbox, _
               vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set Inbox = Nothing
        Set ns = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create DestFolder if DestFolder = ""
    If DestFolder = "" Then
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        MyDocPath = wsh.SpecialFolders.Item("mydocuments")
        DestFolder = MyDocPath & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh-mm-ss")
        If Not fs.FolderExists(DestFolder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder DestFolder
        End If
    End If

    If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Check each message for attachments and extensions
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
            If LCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, Len(ExtString))) = LCase(ExtString) Then
                FileName = DestFolder & Item.SenderName & " " & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                I = I + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item

    ' Show this message when Finished
    If I > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can find the files here : " _
             & DestFolder, vbInformation, "Finished!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If

    ' Clear memory
ThisMacro_exit:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
    Set Inbox = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Sub

    ' Error information
ThisMacro_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
         & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
         & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: SaveEmailAttachmentsToFolder" _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
         & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
         , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume ThisMacro_exit

End Sub
```

*Make sure to update `MyFolder` name to the subfolder you have in Outlook*

*To download `xls`, `xlsx` or `pdf` file, update the following. `->` **`""`***

Example

```
"MyFolder", "xls", "C:\Users\my_name\Documents\ProjectX"
```

Answer (score 0):

This below works for me. It is scaled down from what you are trying to do, but I hope it helps.

```
Sub xWCG_Proc_Item(xMitem As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim xAttCount As Integer 
Dim i As Integer

    'Don't forget to include the reference to Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library in Tools -> References

    xAttCount = CInt(xMitem.Attachments.Count)
    If xAttCount = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 1 To xAttCount
        xMitem.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile ("c:\docume~1\jaywei~1\mydocu~1\" + xMitem.Attachments.Item(i).Filename)
    Next i 
End Sub
```